# What font is "Lunar XChange" on khronos.org

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

I ran across a font at this link (https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) about half way down the page for the "Lunar G" product that says "Lunar XChange". I immediately went to all the popular font identification tools (WhatTheFont!, Identifont, What Font is), and haven't found a match. One distinctive feature that sticks out for this typeface is the lack of crossbar on the "A" character, though I suppose it's possible that it was removed from the font for the purposes of this logo. Other than that, it's you're typical geometric sans-serif typeface.

[image: "Lunar XChange" font in question]

Comment: I was unable to post this second link because of my reputation, but in case it's helpful, I had written: "The font can also be seen here, again, in an image - https://vulkan.lunarg.com/signin"

Answer (score 3):

The closest I could find is Contax, which you can find [here](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typeinnovations/contax/webfont_preview.html). Contax also features a Pro version, with a lot more widths and versions. The open R is almost the same, and the other letters are close. Only the G is significantly different.

[image: Contax]

Other similar fonts:

- [PF Bague Sans Pro](http://myfonts.us/td-Mzykks): The G is closer, but the X is totally different.

[image: Bague Sans]

- [Rams](http://myfonts.us/td-Nkj8cx): On second thought, maybe this one is even closer than Contax.

[image: Rams]

- [Anacharsis](http://myfonts.us/td-UArz3w): Pretty close too, but the U tells us it isn't the one.

[image: Anacharsis]

- [Century Gothic](http://myfonts.us/td-86kWi7): The shorter stock on the L is closer, but still the G is different.

[image: Century Gothic]

- [Mesmerize](http://www.fontspring.com/fonts/typodermic/mesmerize): Also is a failry good match. Extra perk: it's free!

[image: Mesmerize]

Comment: I think Rams is the closest match to the logo. So far every font I have seen has at least 1 letter that just doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

A font that resembles the above logo is the font [Litera TS Bold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ef-typeshop/litera/bold/) but the letters are still inconsistent, especially the G.

[image: Litera TS Bold Example]

---

**EDIT**: After closer inspection, the font Gotham only resembles (after modifying the font) the logo above and is not a match.

A close font (after modifying the font) to the logo above is from the Gotham font family.

[image: Lunar Change comparison]

**I will go over each letter and why I think it fits**

**L** - The crossbar in the L looks to be shortened

**U** - The U overall is unchanged besides shortening the width

**N** - The contrast of the letter is consistent with the N of the logo. It is possible the designer extended the corners of the N to create a sharp angled point.

Here is a quick change I did to the font

[image: font change to the letter N]

**A** - Create a point at the top and take out the crossbar

**R** - It is possible the R is modified from Gotham Book but I am not sure if this is the same font. The contrast is the same and the shape of the top of the R is basically the same except the R width is shortened if using the Gotham font.

**X** - I think this uses Gotham Medium and the height was shortened.

**C** - I don't think it was changed

**H** - Possibly the width was shortened

**G** - Take out the crossbar of the G and a little reshape of the top part.

**E** - The E width would be shortened if using Gotham. The lengths of the crossbars are consistent with the font Gotham.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is not Gotham Book. Why would they take a font and then proceed to change every single letter?

Comment: @PieBie This is just my guess, I don't think it is uncommon for a logo to use a font and change every letter for the logo to make the logo unique and their own. These are all very minor edits to the font (changing the width of the font). I believed this was the font based on very similar letters and consistent contrast and width. I could certainly be wrong... It could also be a different font from the font family but I was going off of what I own.

Comment: And by a different font I mean using Gotham Narrow compared to Gotham Book. I didn't check but you may not need to change as many letters with a different Gotham font.

Comment: Gotham Book doesn't look much like the font pictured

Comment: @ZachSaucier I agree with you and PieBie after looking closer at the font. I have changed my answer to mention that it only resembles the logo.

Comment: Agree that Litera is closer, but the G is way different here as well. Keeps eluding us...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of Monotype Posterama Varients